# SSRS 2008: How to center Column directly above Month tick mark in Column Chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

Using a Column chart. My Category groups are Month and Year, with Month being the inner group so that a three-letter abbreviation of the month is shown directly under the data column and the Year is beneath that set of months. However, the data columns start at a position on the left of the month tick mark (for the first month displayed) and gradually moves to the right of the month tick mark for the last month displayed.

So, how does one set the column to be directly centered on the Month tick mark?

Here is an image of what i have now:[image: Column Chart]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Struggling to find an answer

Comment: Here's the same issue on the graph I have http://i.imgur.com/cYHVg.png

Comment: Also, the wider I set the width of the column, the further away from the central point it appears

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is in Design of the chart. Please know about the series Groups and category groups.

Please check that the Category Groups and Series Groups of the chart. 
The Series Group should not contain the month name and in the category Groups use the month Name field inside the Year field.

Hope this will help. Attached the Images.

Before Modification
[image]
After Modification
[image]

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Business Intelligence Studio, can't see those exact menus, I assume that's from the report builder? Also, my graph is different as per this image http://i.imgur.com/cYHVg.png each series is a custom one. I've manually set the X axis value of each of the series to 1,2,3 etc so that it sits in the right place on the X axis. I don't have any categories set up. Each series just has an X value (1,2,3 etc) and a Y value (the actual 1-10 value I'm interested in) if that makes sense?

Comment: This windows are from the Business Intelligence Studio itself. Click on the chart Data bar in the Design View. This will automatically pop-up on the right side of the chart. Say your values 1,2,3 are the countofsome fields. These are the value fields. For the comparison of the months and year you are getting the problem to center the chart. Updated the full view of the chart. Update your question with the design view also for any further information.

Comment: Hi, is it Visual Studio 2008 as I don't have the same view, this is what it looks like in design view http://i.imgur.com/SIHRl.png

Comment: As you can see I don't have categories or series directly, I have 6 data fields, each of which displays as 1 bar on the graph. Each of those data fields has an X and Y value as described above, it all works apart from the alignment problem where it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/cYHVg.png

Comment: I had done the Report in the SQL Server 2008 R2 Business Intelligence management studio comes with the SQL Server 2008 R2. In 2008 how the reports are designed I don't know.

Comment: Maybe that was an addition in R2. The underlying data is the same though, no "series groups" and no "category groups". I'll carry on trying to work out what it is. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: As I can see from your Design View. Figure out how to use the "Drop series fields here" and "Drop Category fields here". Its the same I am speaking about. No need to group the data. Designer will automatically group the data. If you use all these properly.